# How to correct use if checkboxes were submited in PHP, SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If checkbox was submited = do something.
For example,on main page tasks are already sorted by ID by default ,but if checkbox was submited tasks must be sorted by another value.

```
           //index.php
           <form method="POST">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <h4>Sort by:</h4>
                       <label><input type="checkbox" name="name_user" value="username"> User Name </label><br>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="useremail"> User Email </label><br>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="latest"> Latest </label><br>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="status"> Status </label><br>
                        <button type="submit"  name="submit"class="btn btn-primary btn-sort">Sort</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

SQL Query

```
//class Task
public static function getTask($page = 1){

    $page = intval($page);
    $offset = ($page - 1) * 3;

    $db = Db::getConnection();
    $taskList = [];

    $result = $db->query('SELECT id, user_name, user_email, title, image, tasktext, status FROM task '
            . 'ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET '. $offset );
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
        $taskList[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
        $taskList[$i]['user_name'] = $row['user_name'];
        $taskList[$i]['user_email'] = $row['user_email'];
        $taskList[$i]['title'] = $row['title'];
        $taskList[$i]['image'] = $row['image'];
        $taskList[$i]['tasktext'] = $row['tasktext'];
        $taskList[$i]['status'] = $row['status'];
        $i++;
    }
    return $taskList;
}
```

Im trying to do something like this

```
class IndexController{

public function actionIndex($page = 1){

    $userId = User::checkLogged();
    $taskboard = Task::getTask($page); //show sort by default(works fine)

    //if I submited button = sort by email
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) == 'useremail'){
        $taskboard = Task::sortByEmail($page);
    }
    //should sort by defaul again
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) == 'latest'){
        $taskboard = Task::getTask($page);
    }


    require_once (ROOT.'/views/index/index.php');
    return true;
}}
```

But its not sorting, whats wrong?

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit']) == 'X')` are false positives. They need to be broken up into two separate conditions. Plus, you're checking for the wrong input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a common name attribute to all your checkboxes, like below.

```
//index.php
<form method="POST">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <h4>Sort by:</h4>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sort_by" value="username"> User Name </label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sort_by" value="useremail"> User Email </label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sort_by" value="latest"> Latest </label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="sort_by" value="status"> Status </label><br>
    <button type="submit"  name="submit"class="btn btn-primary btn-sort">Sort</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Then your PHP code should be like below - evaluating the value of the checkbox and not that of the submit button.

```
class IndexController{

public function actionIndex($page = 1){

    $userId = User::checkLogged();
    $sort_by = isset($_POST['sort_by']) ? $_POST['sort_by'] : 'latest'; //defaults to 'latest' if $_POST['sort_by'] is not set

    //if I submited button = sort by email
    if($sort_by == 'useremail'){
        $taskboard = Task::sortByEmail($page);
    }
    //should sort by defaul again
    else{
        $taskboard = Task::getTask($page);
    }


    require_once (ROOT.'/views/index/index.php');
    return true;
}}
```

Comment: Works nice, thanks a lot it helps, but now I have Notice: Undefined index: sort_by in {path}
Any tips how to fix it? my error_reporting turned ON, should I turn it off in production?

Comment: i posted edits above to resolve the undefined index issues, and set sort_by default value. you can use elseif to add your other conditions.

Comment: Thanks, you helped a lot.